# Color Shading with Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

It was easy to do in Excel, but I am having trouble following some of the scripts written on here.  Basically we have 3 colors we use, Green, Yellow and Red.  1 = Green, 2 = Yellow and 3 = Red. What I would like to happen is the shading change depending on the number. So if the field has a value of 1, it will be green, if it has 1.5 it will be a greenish, yellow tint.  Is there a way for me to do this, or can anyone pass over some simple custom expressions that I could tweak for this?

Answer (score 1):

The [Conditional Formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) rules can accomplish that.

Result:

[image: Colours]

Rules:

[image: Rules]